# Django template html file can't find WebGL Build and TemplateData folders

Tags: python, django, webgl

To practise my Django skills, I want to try to host a game on my website.  The game was made in Unity and packaged using WebGL.

I used the index.html created by WebGL as a Django template and created the URL path and view in the relevant locations.  WebGL creates two folders, Build and TemplateData that are referenced in index.html.

I have tried putting these folders in with the html templates, and on every level in my Django folder structure.

The outcome is the same wherever I put the folders.  The GET command is sent but a "Not Found: /TemplateData/filename...." is shown for a few files

Does anyone know how to see where the GET command is looking, or just where the folders should go?

Thanks,
Sophie

Answer (score 4):

After some more messing about I found that you can just wham everything into the static folder and then reference it in index.html the same way you pick up css files in base.html

```
    {% load static %}
       .....some more code

    <script>
        var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "{% static 
       'Build/Juno_WebGL.json' %}", {onProgress: UnityProgress});
    </script>
```

Do this for every reference to the files in index.html

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue recently and came across this thread. Here was my solution for anyone who may come across this in the future.

take the index.html file generated and put it in your templates folder, create a link through to this template using the standard django, url, view, template flow e.g:

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('unity/', views.unity, name='unity'),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
def unity(request):
    return render(request, template_name='mainapp/unity.html')
```

Take your WebGL build files and put them somewhere in your static folder. Finally edit your index.html so that it includes {% load static %} and look for any href's in the file and point these to your static folder, do the same for any scripts. E.g. My Unity builds WebGL application had a 'var buildUrl = "Build";' line which I had to point towards my static folder.

```
Example:

<!--block content etc.. -->

{% load static %}

    <html lang="en-us">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Unity WebGL Player | UnityApp</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'unity/TemplateData/favicon.ico' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'unity/TemplateData/style.css' %}">
      </head>

       <!-- etc.. -->

      <body>
        <script>
          var buildUrl = "../static/unity/Build";
          var loaderUrl = buildUrl + "/Unity App.loader.js";
            // etc..
        
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```